# How to use a fullScreen in YouTube (webview)?

Tags: java, android, webview, youtube, fullscreen

I have this code:

`public class Boxeo extends Fragment {`

```
WebView appWeb;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_tab, container, false);


      appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
    appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //Cargamos el enlace definido
    appWeb.loadUrl(url);
    //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
    appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

But not works fullscreen, and I try this code:

```
    public class Boxeo extends Fragment {
WebView appWeb;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.four_tab, container, false);

    String url = "<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxORtskANEIq4iBrXbMQvUtIQi_oDCk6c\" frameBorder=\"0\" \"allowFullScreen=\"allowFullScreen\"> </iframe>";

            appWeb = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //Habilitamos el javaScript y el zoom
    appWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //appWeb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //Cargamos el enlace definido
    appWeb.loadUrl(url);
    //Este método es para que el navegador se quede en nuestra aplicación
    appWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

But... I am totally sad because it doesn't works, why?? I need some **library imports** ??

Update:

I have a `BottomBar` and I need that (with `WebView`) that the user **only** can see a fullscreen video with `bottomBar` at the bottom. And the video now only takes up a third of the screen and **I can`t put fullscreen, it's impossible** .

I'll try to upload a photo tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Is your activity specified as fullscreen?
If no, try add in activity on create method:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Or your webview doesn't fit to activity size? In this case provide the screenshot of current view and notes for expected view.

Comment: alex? what do yout hink?

Answer (score 0):

go with this method :-

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```